# Split string using delimiter and use it in an in statement

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

We have two tables first of which contains a code for each task in each run. The 2nd table contains codes of all tasks in each run. How do I run a spark sql splitting the column in 2nd table based on a delimiter and use it in and IN statement in the first table

The tables look like this

Table f1

```
+-------+-----+--+
| runid | tid |  |
+-------+-----+--+
| 1a    | cb4 |  |
| 1a    | hb5 |  |
| 1a    | hb6 |  |
| 1b    | gh6 |  |
| 1b    | gh7 |  |
| 1c    | kl9 |  |
+-------+-----+--+
```

Table f2

```
+-------+-------------+
| runid |     tid     |
+-------+-------------+
| 1a    | cb4,hb5,hb6 |
| 1b    | gh6,gh7,gh8 |
+-------+-------------+
```

I have tried split but it doesn't seem to be working and regexp_extract doesnt appear to help

```
select e.* from f1 e inner join
f2 a 
on e.runid=a.runid where e.runid in ('1a',
'1b') and e.tid in (select split(a.tid, '[,]') from f2)
```

Desired output would be

```
+-------+-----+
| runid | tid |
+-------+-----+
| 1a    | cb4 |
| 1a    | hb5 |
| 1a    | hb6 |
| 1b    | gh6 |
| 1b    | gh7 |
+-------+-----+
```

I am rookie as far a spark sql is concerned. Any help would be very appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Use `lateral view` with `explode` to get one tid per row and then use it for `join`.

```
with exploded_f2 as
(select runid,tid,expl_tid
 from f2
 lateral view explode(split(tid,',')) tbl as expl_tid
) 
select f1.*
from f1
join exploded_f2 f2 on f1.tid = f2.expl_tid
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another version:

```
val df3 = df2.flatMap {x => x.getString(1).split(",")
             .map(y => (x.getString(0),y))}.toDF("runid","tid2")
df3.show()

+-----+----+
|runid|tid2|
+-----+----+
|   1a| cb4|
|   1a| hb5|
|   1a| hb6|
|   1b| gh6|
|   1b| gh7|
|   1b| gh8|
+-----+----+
```

Then join df1 and df3

```
df1.join(df3, "runid").select($"runid", $"tid").distinct.show(false)

+-----+---+
|runid|tid|
+-----+---+
|1a   |hb5|
|1b   |gh7|
|1b   |gh6|
|1a   |hb6|
|1a   |cb4|
+-----+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

## Loading data as pipe delimited flat file

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
schema=StructType([StructField("runid",StringType()),StructField("tid",StringType())])
f1=spark.read.format("csv").schema(schema).option("header","true").option("delimiter","|").load("c:/tmp/f1.csv")
f2=spark.read.format("csv").schema(schema).option("header","true").option("delimiter","|").load("c:/tmp/f2.csv")
```

## explode by using comma as a delimiter and rename the exploded column as tid

```
f2_alter=(f2.withColumn("tid_explode",explode(split(f2.tid,"[,]")))).select("runid",col("tid_explode").alias("tid"))
```

## do a join on runid and tid

```
df2=f1.join(f2_alter,["runid","tid"]).show()


+-----+---+
|runid|tid|
+-----+---+
|   1a|cb4|
|   1a|hb5|
|   1a|hb6|
|   1b|gh6|
|   1b|gh7|
+-----+---+
```